# php server not opening socket google compute

Tags: php, sockets, google-compute-engine

I have a google compute engine instance running. I installed php5, apache2 and mysql on the compute engine instance. 
I have opened up the port in the firewall settings as well "tcp:3000"
I have then put this code up in /var/www/ folder to open a php server and do some custom replies.

However Its not able to open and bind socket. Can you please help?

This is my code:

```
<?php 
error_reporting(0);
set_time_limit(0);
date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Calcutta');
$address = 'localhost';
$port = 3000;
$max_clients = 10;
$datetime = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
if(!($sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, SOL_TCP)))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        writeToFile('edmerrorlog.txt', $datetime." :: ".'Couldnt create socket: ['.$errorcode.']'. $errormsg);
}

echo "New Socket created \n";
/*if (!socket_set_option($sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, 1)) { 
    echo socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)); 
        writeToFile('edmerrorlog.txt', $datetime." :: ".socket_strerror(socket_last_error($sock)));
    exit; 
} 
*/

// Bind the source address
if( !socket_bind($sock, $address , $port) )
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not bind socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        writeToFile('edmerrorlog.txt', $datetime." :: ".'Could not bind socket : ['.$errorcode.']'. $errormsg);
}

echo "Socket bind OK \n";

if(!socket_listen ($sock , 10))
{
    $errorcode = socket_last_error();
    $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

    die("Could not listen on socket : [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        writeToFile('edmerrorlog.txt', $datetime." :: ".'Could not listen on socket1 : ['.$errorcode.']'. $errormsg);
}
```

Comment: I was able to create the socket in a fresh Debian instance. 
Can you access through the browser to your remote files? If not you'll need to go to the instance details in the Developers Console and tick the 'Allow HTTP traffic' check box.

Comment: I have recreated again from scratch and I haven’t needed nothing special:

1- I created a fresh instance
2- Installed apache2 and php5
3- Created a file.php with your code

After that, it worked running the following command from the instance:
`curl 127.0.0.1/file.php`

Later, I clicked on "Allow HTTP traffic" in order to access from the browser and it worked as well.

Comment: For me it's opening socket on some random port instead of specified port in method socket_bind($sock, $address , $port). Can someone please suggest what can be the cause for same?